# How can I have a Label in a UIStackView and allow clipping?

Tags: xcode, constraints, uistackview, clipping

I am making a music app. the app works when rotated horizontally.  I have 3 objects in line with each other: elapsedTime, songTitle, remainingTime.  The problem is that when elapsedTime switches from 00:00 to 00:01, it causes the other 2 objects to move.  They jiggle.  I'd like that to stop.  I don't remember this happening with Xcode 8 or 9 but I could be wrong.

I've tried using fixed widths, especially for the label: songTitle.  But Xcode has a fit.  It says: "Fixed width constraints may cause clipping".  But, I'm ok with that.  The Xcode solutions are to remove it or set it to greater than or equal to current width.  Doesn't help.

Currently, I'm trying UIStackView, but I'm not getting anywhere.
The only constraint on the stackView is height.  Currently there are no constraints on the 3 objects.
Axis is Horizontal
Alignment is Center
Distribution is Equal Spacing
Spacing is 5

Comment: I've studied the "duplicate" link and thus have tried a whole bunch of things.  It still doesn't work.  I disagree that this is a duplicate post.  I know that this post has the "fixed width constraints ..." in common, but I am trying to get the jiggling to stop.

Comment: I finally got rid of the "jiggle".  I've tried so many things... Basically, I believe that increasing the width of my 2 "time" objects and putting constraints on their widths, did the trick.  I am still using a StackView.  The link taught me about the autoshink feature and while it doesn't have anything to do with the "jiggling", I choose to use it.  Thanks for that.  I have to say, that it is very frustrating that when you delete a constraint (while testing/learning), Xcode decides to change the width of something.  You end up chasing your tail.